# Check If Java Interface Method Is Populated

Tags: java

I have an interface where I implemented the following method:
`public void shutdown()`
Quite a few of the classes that implement this method will not actually use it. Is there a way to check if the body of the implementation actually has some content in it?

I suppose I could add a `boolean` check, but I'd like to avoid additional overhead.

Comment: Here's another thought:  why are classes that don't need to implement this method being forced to implement this method?

Comment: Why do you care? If the method does nothing then calling it will do nothing. Further, as @Makoto points out; if a class does not actually _implement_ the interface then why does it?

Comment: Because every class that implements an interface needs to implement every method.

Comment: If many classes implementing the interface don't need the method, then the method most likely doesn't belong in the interface. Rethink the design; you may be better off creating subclasses where you need the additional function.

Comment: Implement an abstract class that implements that interface.  Your abstract class can have a default implementation.  All the other classes that extends from that abstract class can then have the option to not implement the shutdown() method.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. First, you don't implement methods in an interface. Only classes implement methods. Second, you say that the classes don't **use** the `shutdown()` method, but then you try to find a way to see if they truly **implement** it. Maybe you can shed more light about what you mean and why you need to know?

Comment: If you just want the polymorphism, then you can use an abstract class

Comment: @beyonddc that's _so_ Java 7. What's wrong with a `default` method on the `interface` itself if you are going down that route?

Comment: Unfortunately, the project is built on Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

In your subclass, you can throw a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` in `shutdown()` if there is no implementation.

Your calling class will just need to catch that exception then you'll know exactly what class doesn't implement that method.

Comment: This is ***ugly*** but it will work.  I think it's best just to not implement an interface on a class if you don't need its method.

Comment: @markspace: Surely, that depends on the context in which the method is used? Certainly, this is the way most standard library classes do it, like read-only `Iterator`s, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just not implementing anything at all?  Guessing at your api, look at something like `ExecutorService`:

```
// run the service
     try {
       for (;;) {
         pool.execute(new Handler(serverSocket.accept()));
       }
     } catch (IOException ex) {
       pool.shutdown();
     }
```

If `shutdown()` in the above code did nothing, would it really matter?  Assuming the pool would shutdown eventually when all threads completed.

Trying to check before you call a method seems like another type of [Conditional Test Antipattern.](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)  The point of polymorphism is that you aren't supposed to need to check, the method should handle all cases.  It's encapsulated.  An empty body in a method just means the object didn't need to handle that case.

I'm just trying to make certain you have thought this all the way through.  Sometimes an empty method body works, and sometimes it won't.  Just try to consider what happens if you don't implement anything at all.  Will it function correctly, and make your code simpler?  If it does, use it.

If not, then I think a boolean test should be added to your interface, something like `canShutdown()` for those objects that actually are able to implement a proper shutdown method.

```
public interface MyShutdown {
   boolean canShutdown();
   void shutdown();
}
```

This feels at least semi-clean to me.